# Why are PostAsJsonAsync's parameters not included in the post as JSON content?

Tags: json, xamarin, xamarin.ios

IT is very disapointing that after one week i cannot solve a simple problem of posting a JSON content to a Web Server's API. I think I will quit this attempt to use Xamarin.

I am trying to post the JSON parameters below using `PostAsJsonAsync` in a Xamarin app. The program does post the site but the parameters are not encoded as JSON content. Does anyone know why?

```
public async void Login()
{
    var formcontent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("email","marcio@netopen.com.br"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password","Xy345")
    });
    var FlyVIPAPI = new HttpClient();
    var request = await FlyVIPAPI.PostAsJsonAsync("http://www.ik.com.br/app/api/LoginUser.php", formcontent);
    var response = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    //var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
    var RepostaJson = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(response);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(RepostaJson["success"]);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(RepostaJson["error"]);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LoginRequest
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}

public async void Login()
{
    using (var FlyVIPAPI = new HttpClient())
    {
        // Create Request object
        var requestObj = new LoginRequest { email = "marcio@netopen.com.br", password = "Xy345" };

        // Serialize to JSON string
        var formcontent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestObj);

        // Create HTTP content
        var content = new StringContent(formcontent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        // POST Request
        var request = await FlyVIPAPI.PostAsync("http://www.ik.com.br/app/api/LoginUser.php", content);

        // Read Response
        var response = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        ....
    }
}
```

Additionally, I would suggest wrapping your `HttpClient` in a `using` statement so that is will be disposed of once your code block is done. Freeing up resources.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: I replace my code by your suggestion and the result is the same. The post is being sent without the JSON encoded parameters

Comment: @user3358125 I think I misunderstood your issue, are you wanting to do a POST with url parameter not body content?

Comment: @user3358125 I have updated the answer now showing with URL parameters

Comment: I would like to do a POST with a JSON encoded body content

Comment: @user3358125 I have updated the answer, I think I finally understand what you wanted to do, hope it works :)

Comment: PlaceHold3 it does not work. The POST is sent without the JSON content.